# Add existing item in VS2010 project programmatically?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

How can I add existing item in solution explorer programmatically (i.e., at run time) in a 
Visual studio 2010 project ?

existing items may include images,videos etc

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. You are asking how to add files and folders to a project (or solution folder?) while a solution and its projects are loaded in visual studio?

Comment: i want to add files to solution folder of a project programatically @RitchMelton

Comment: Projects don't have solution folders, solutions do.

Comment: oh sorry, actually i want to add existing items from my pc to project folder programatically

Comment: Duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852746/dynamically-add-a-file-in-project-using-c-sharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852746/dynamically-add-a-file-in-project-using-c-sharp)

Comment: The question is tagged C# so as such I'm assuming you need to do this from C# code, but if you ever need to do it via something closer to scripting, using the PowerConsole extension is very easy and powerful IME. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/67620d8c-93dd-4e57-aa86-c9404acbd7b3

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely end up using Visual Studio's existing automation framework for this, or something that wraps it.

In particular, once you get a reference to the project, you'll access its ProjectItems property to get the collection of items in the project, and then use either AddFromFile or AddFromFileCopy depending on whether you want to add the original at its existing location or a copy to be placed within the project dir.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitems.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitems.addfromfile.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitems.addfromfilecopy.aspx

the DTE object is kind of the 'root' of the automation object model - for more info, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6d9sf9k.aspx